# load new webpage after loading the present one

Tags: javascript

`Goal:
I have a text file which consists of list of URLs separated by '\n'.
My goal is to pass them into an array and load them sequentially after a page gets loaded.

My code:

```
    <html>
    <head> </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allText =[];
        var allTextLines = [];
    var Lines = [];
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

    txtFile.open("GET", "URL.txt", true);
    var i=0;
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function URL()
    {
        if (txtFile.readyState == 4)
        {
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            document.write(allText);
            window.location.href=allTextLines[i++];
            window.onload=setTimeout(URL,1000);
        }
    }
        txtFile.send(null);
  </script>
  </html>
```

I tried for loop. But, the browser keeps stuck in processing.
Any insights on how to do it?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you change the location using `window.location.href` the rest of the javascript you write will be ignored - and the javascript within the new location will be run (if any). If you wanted to do this you'd need to use an `<iframe>` so that you can control the location without losing control of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If the new urls are on the same domain you could use the new html5 pushState method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Example